# Delete folders using regex

Tags: regular-expression

I would like to delete folders with specified `regex`, but I could not build a good `regex`.

I have:

```
/root
  /my-picture-2015
    /my-picture-2015-1
    /my-picture-2015-2
  /my-picture-2015-1
  /my-picture-2015-2
  /my-picture-2015-3
etc.
```

Directory `my-picture-2015` is a backup which I would like restored. It could stay in this directory, but I have to delete all `my-picture-2015-X` only from `root` directory. Directories in `my-picture-2015` have to stay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply:

```
rm -rf /root/my-picture-2015-*/
```

Comment: and it will not remove : `/root/my-pictures-2015/my-pictures-2015-1` ?

Answer (score 2):

If you are inside the `root` directory, then you can use this command to delete the required folders:

```
find -type d -maxdepth 1 -iregex ".*my-picture-[0-9]*-[0-9]" -exec rm -r {} +
```

Here,

```
-maxdepth   ==>   do no descend beyond the first level for searching
```